# What are good chess tournaments to play in Europe as a USCF Class A + age 21+?

Tags: tournament, fide

I'm looking for a good European chess tournament to play that would be good for my age and playing strength. Perhaps even meet more chess player close to my age group. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this is too broad as it is currently stated, could you precise the location you'd prefer and an estimated date?

Comment: @Adolfo Ideally a chess tournament anywhere in Italy around the late Spring to early Fall would be great. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to the monthly "First Saturday" round-robin tournaments in Budapest. (You probably have heard of it, it has been in existence for like 22 years.)
The city is nice, the venue is downtown, the local girls are beautiful, the majority of the players speak/understand English, maybe the only issue can be that your rating qualifies you for group "FM-A", where the opponents are rated between FIDE 1850 and 2100. But 9-11 games are guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I played in [Reykjavik](http://www.reykjavikopen.com) two years ago and it was fantastic!

Of course that's not quite Italy …

Closer to your specification is probably the [Open in Pula](http://www.skpula.hr/Pula%20Open%202015/en/engleski%20raspis%20%202015.pdf). I have never been there, but from what I've heard, if you want to combine beach holiday and chess, that's a good opportunity.

I did play [an open in Italy](http://www.4salentochessopen2015.it/?lang=en) as well, quite nice, but also quite small.

Comment: As a chess player living in the United States, how do I register for the next Open Pula? I also don't have a FIDE rating, how would it work?

Comment: There is a online registration form on the homepage: http://www.skpula.hr/Pula%20Open%202015/en/index%20en%2015.htm